# Python library conflict with lower version

Tags: centos, python, rpm, dependencies

I am trying to reinstall yum in `CentOS`. Because I made some mistake by removing python.

```
so I got error as follows
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   No module named rpm

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.4.3 (#1, Nov 11 2010, 13:34:43) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to 
the yum faq at:
  http://wiki.linux.duke.edu/YumFaq
```

And then I followed some tutorial from http://www.electrictoolbox.com/install-yum-with-rpm-on-centos/
But I got an error while trying to install python libs

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    python < 2.4.3-32.el5 conflicts with python-libs-2.4.3-43.el5.i386
```

How can I fix this?

**Edit**

```
rpm -qa|grep python
python-iniparse-0.2.3-4.el5
python-2.4.3-27.el5_5.3
libselinux-python-1.33.4-5.5.el5
gamin-python-0.1.7-8.el5
python-elementtree-1.2.6-5
python-urlgrabber-3.1.0-6.el5
audit-libs-python-1.7.17-3.el5
libxml2-python-2.6.26-2.1.2.8.el5_5.1
python-sqlite-1.1.7-1.2.1
```

Comment: Can you state your centos version? Also a list of the currently installed relevant packages eg. python and related packages, yum etc along with versions. also, why were you trying to remove python?

Comment: I'm new at Linux. I wanna update python with new lib, and then I remove the existing python using yum remove python. I don't know that there are so much library depend on python

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "python with new lib". Did you want a new library? In general python versions are tightly coupled the the rest of the system, and cannot be changed without breakage. There seems to be a version mismatch. Is your system perhaps out of date? I first suggest you try to find a version of `python-libs` that your installed python will work with. once you have your system working, I suggest checking for updates.

Answer (score 1):

I checked on the web, and (on the assumption that you are using Centos 5.5, which you have not confirmed), 2.4.3-32 corresponds to 5.5, but 2.4.3-43 corresponds to 5.6.

You presumably want to update to 5.6. So get python 2.4.3-43 and upgrade to that using `rpm -Uvh`. [This link](http://pkgs.org/centos-5-rhel-5/centos-rhel-i386/python-2.4.3-43.el5.i386.rpm.html) will probably work. You can use a [direct link](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/i386/CentOS/python-2.4.3-43.el5.i386.rpm) if you want. If that works, try installing python-libs as you did earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Using just RPM, remove the old libraries and reinstall all the Python 2.4 interpreter and libraries, including the Python rpm module.

Comment: I've tried to remove existing python using `rpm -e python-2.4.3-27.el5_5.3`

But I Got error as follows:
error: Failed dependencies:
 libpython2.4.so.1.0 is needed by (installed) libsemanage-1.9.1-4.4.el5.i386
 python(abi) = 2.4 is needed by (installed) rhpl-0.194.1-1.i386